# AEM: Using Reverse Proxy - Dispatcher

Tags: apache, aem, reverse-proxy, dispatcher

Could you please let me know how can we use reverse proxy to allow non aem server to post pages to a directory on the main domain on AEM site (Eg: [www.yourdomainname.com/test-one](http://www.yourdomainname.com/test-one))?

I have tried adding the below syntax in the vhost file in dispatcher module of Apache server for using reverse proxy. However, this didn't work and faced a 404 on dispatcher upon server restart. The reason might be dispatcher reverse proxies to the publish instance. How can we bypass this issue to setup reverse proxy?

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.yourdomainname.com
        ProxyRequests off
        RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
        Header set  xxx-Proxy-Version "1.0"
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        <Location /test-one >
            ProxyPass "http://xxx/test-one"
            ProxyPassReverse "http://xxx/test-one"
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Location>

        <Location /test-one/(.*) >
            ProxyPass "http://xxx/test-one/(.*)"
            ProxyPassReverse "http://xxx/test-one/(.*)"
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to serve the /test-one/* subpath of your domain from a different (non-AEM)  server? This is normally not a problem, and using Apaches mod_proxy is the correct way to do it. If this is so, you should re-phrase your question. I can help you. But then we would also need more information, how you configured your Apache, and more details on the error. Otherwise I can only say, that you are on the right way - and someone with Apache knowledge could help you (no AEM knowledge required).

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow ram. **allow non aem server to post pages to a directory on the main domain** - does this mean that another website can call the url to put a page to be stored on AEM? or you wanted to have the other website accessible through that `/test-one/` url?

Comment: @BagusTesa I want a landing page from non aem site to be accessible on our domain at /test-one url. Thanks

Comment: alright, i want to be sure, is the 404 happens only on the `/test-one/` url while the rest of AEM runs properly?

Comment: @BagusTesa I've added the above syntax for reverse proxy and restarted the server. It then throws a 404 on entire dispatcher not just specific url. Also, I don not see enough info in the error log.

Comment: @Ram, i found [this](https://medium.com/swlh/apache-reverse-proxy-content-from-different-websites-3e82df87a34a) but i'm not sure if it will help. my experience with aem dispatcher wasnt a nice one, last time it was kind of finicky with `mod_rewrite` - but it was an old dispatcher for adobecq 5.6 i think.